# PHP same script for Uploading file on another server is not working

Tags: php, apache, server

I have simple PhP script that is working fine on one of my server but when i placed it on my another server and it's not working. What can be the possible reason for it... Here is my script

```
<?php
  $objFile = & $_FILES["file"];
  $strPath = basename( $objFile["name"] );
  $fname =  $_POST["fname"];

  if( move_uploaded_file( $objFile["tmp_name"], $strPath ) ) {
    print "The file " .  $strPath . " has been uploaded. my vavirable name is ".$fname;
   } else {
    print "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: Even I discard the if else part and print the values for my variables  $strPath and $fname; it returns empty string and on my other free hosting server it is giving me the required values.

Comment: did  you check folder permission for the folder where you upload files.

Comment: @sandeepsure this is what I'm thinking becuase this hosting is provided me by my client and other one is mine where every thing is working perfectly.. what kind of permission might be missing for me on my client's server???

Comment: add permission with `chmod` http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: have you tried dumping you `$GLOBALS` like so: `var_dump($GLOBALS);` to check where the input ended up?

Answer (score 1):

Echo this fields and find what is printed.

```
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

I think there is a space between & and $_FILES["file"]; be a problem.

```
$objFile = & $_FILES["file"];
```

Comment: check your html  input type should be file and name should be file as you have mentioned    $_FILES["file"]

Comment: As i already mentioned that this is working fine on my another server so it is suppose to work here as well ... all the variable names are placed correctly